# Express with Vercel can't import other files

Tags: node.js, express, vercel

I've been experimenting with Express on Vercel and it straight up can't work when importing other files (NodeJS modules work fine though)

This is the root of my project:

```
.
├── app.ts
├── node_modules
├── package.json
├── package-lock.json
├── routes
└── vercel.json

2 directories, 4 files
```

This is the `app.ts`

```
import express from "express";

import testRouter from "./routes/route.js";
// Middlewares
const app = express();

app.use(testRouter);
app.get("/", (req, res) => res.send("Hello World"));

// connection
const port = process.env.PORT || 4000;
app.listen(port, () => console.log(`Listening to port ${port}`));
```

This is the `./routes/route.js`

```
import { Router } from "express";

const router = Router();

router.get("/test", (req, res) => {
    res.send("Hello world from test route");
});

export default router;
```

This is my `vercel.json`

```
{
    "builds": [
        {
            "src": "./app.ts",
            "use": "@vercel/node"
        }
    ],
    "routes": [
        {
            "src": "/(.*)",
            "dest": "app.ts"
        }
    ]
}
```

However, when deployed to vercel this is the error I face:
[image]